# PDO::FETCH_COLUMN fetches nothing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following code gives me an array `$a` containing `description`.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT description, id
    FROM money_items");
$stmt->execute();
$a = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$id = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 1);
```

But the `$id` array comes out blank.

```
   Array
   (
   )
```

If I remove the `$a = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);` line, the `$id` array comes out fine. Am I only allowed to fetch one column from the results?

Comment: @TobyAllen Well, that provided a solution for the issue. Thanks! But why does that second array come out empty?

Comment: The first call to `fetchAll` consumes all data from the query, so when the time of the second call comes, it has nothing to consume, therefore the empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This will fetch all columns and all rows to an array -

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

To answer your actual question though, I would  **guess** that the FetchAll function called on the statement runs through all the rows, so the internal pointer in the array is at the end when you fetch the second column.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a command to reset the pointer to row 0 again?

Comment: There is but I don't know it, if you look through the pdo docs on php.net you should find it.