# Fetching structure of empty table in database using PDO (in PHP OOP script)

Tags: php, pdo

I am new into programming and I have a problem with my php script. I couldn't find a working solution so I'll try here.

I am trying to get structure of my table in database with PHP through PDO. I don't need the actual data I just need the structure because if someone alter and change the structure across the versions of my app I don't want to go so deep into my code and changing it again and again and again.

So I tried this but it just returns me an empty array. It works only with some data in table.

```
  //Function for showing all existing permission in system
  public function showExistingPermissions(){
    $sql = $this->db->prepare('DESCRIBE os_settings_level');
    $sql->execute();
    $r = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    return $r;
  }
```

When I switch this code to table which is not empty it actually works exactly how I need to.

Thank you for any tips!

PS: I forgot to mention that I am using this script with fresh and clean start of app so there is NO ENTERES in table yet... That's why it's fetching an empty array I am trying now to get the structure even when the table is empty.

Comment: You're not specifying an index for your column.  Maybe you need `$r = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO::FETCH\_COLUMN fetches nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530071/pdofetch-column-fetches-nothing)

Comment: Just try changing it to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Comment: Not working, nor using index for column neither fetching the ASSOC :/ It actually fetches something in my code but not when the table is empty... Can't I possibly do something like WHERE 'ID' = 0 or some trick like this?

Comment: The above code will work even if there are no rows in a table, DESCRIBE isn't dependant on the number of rows.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?` ... `?` being the database name, then group the `TABLE_NAME`, which will give you the cols, types etc, then you know what to create. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/71695

Comment: Thank you all It works like a charm. Thank you!